# it is not clear what the structure is/it is not clear what is the structure?

Tags: word-order

Which one is correct: "it is not clear what IS the structure comprising two enzymes..." or "it is not clear what the structure comprising two enzymes IS ..." ? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please finish reading the [tour] which explains the purpose of this site. It should be clear that it is not for learners asking basic questions. That is why we have a sister site, [ell.se].

Comment: They are both OK. It's a matter of personal preference, not grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to say it is the latter. “What is” creates a question in an awkward place in the first example. Your statement is expressing doubt, so the latter works best.

Comment: Why can't we say "It is not clear [what is the structure comprising two enzymes]"? The bracketed subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question) follows the rule that such clauses do not (normally) have subject-auxiliary inversion.

Comment: It grates on the tongue (it doesn’t sound correct). You would have to say: “it is not clear what the structure comprising two enzymes is” for the example you give. “What is” is a direct query.

Comment: It sounds fine to me. The clause is a subordinate interrogative. Unlike a main clause interrogative, it expresses a question but does not directly ask one, and it is certainly grammatical.